# Start fullpage.js on middle slide

Tags: jquery, fullpage.js

I need to make the 3rd slide, out of 5, active but at the moment I can't seem to do it using .

An example of what I would like to do would be if this page loaded:

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

But, when you scrolled down the slider is actually waiting on this slide:

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/#secondPage/1

I know I'm miles off with the following:

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    anchors: ['home', 'intro', 'industry-sectors', 'get-started', 'pricing'],
    afterRender: function(){
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
        $.fn.fullpage.moveSlideRight();
    }
});
```

I can only find bits of code and not a complete solution. Do I really have to alter the speed of the animations and shuffle it and then [reset the speeds](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/127)? Or use something [like this](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js/issues/129)?

Is there no way of just adding 'active' or similar to the slide?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the latest version of fullpage.js (v2.0.5) you will be able to do it by just adding the `active` class to the section and slide in which you want the plugin to start.

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/97tbk/98/)

As simple as:

```
<div id="fullpage">
    <div class="section">One</div>
    <div class="section active">
        <div class="slide">Two</div>
        <div class="slide">Three</div>
        <div class="slide active">Four</div>
    </div>
    <div class="section">Five</div>
    <div class="section">Six</div>
</div>
```

The methods you are using they only are applied to the active section. That's why it is not working for you if you are trying to slide the slides of a non active section.

Comment: Thanks, that's great to start like that, but I'd like the _slide_ to be active, but the _section above_ (standard, first section) to be active on page load. http://jsfiddle.net/Dszn9/2/

Comment: Then you should modify the plugin as detailed in the link you posted.